# Selecting from mulitple tables, then joining to both, in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Say if I have a database structure a bit like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    idPerson    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name        VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE detailTypes (
    type            INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    field           VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE details (
    idPerson        INT NOT NULL,
    idDetailType    INT NOT NULL,
    value           VARCHAR(50)
);
```

With this data:

```
|----------|---------|
| idPerson | Name    |
|----------|---------|
| 1        | Tom     |
| 2        | Dick    |
| 3        | Harry   |
|----------|---------|

|----------|----------|
| type     | field    |
|----------|----------|
| 1        | Diet     |
| 2        | Hat size |
|----------|----------|

|----------|------|------------|
| idPerson | type | value      |
|----------|------|------------|
| 1        | 1    | Vegetarian |
| 1        | 2    | Medium     |
| 2        | 2    | Small      |
|----------|------|------------|
```

And I want a result which looks like this:

```
|----------|----------|------------|
| Name     | field    | value      |
|----------|----------|------------|
| Tom      | Diet     | Vegetarian |
| Tom      | Hat Size | Medium     |
| Dick     | Diet     | NULL       |
| Dick     | Hat Size | Small      |
| Harry    | Diet     | NULL       |
| Harry    | Hat Size | NULL       |
|----------|----------|------------|
```

I would think, correct me if I'm wrong, that the query that ought to achieve this should look like:

```
SELECT name, field, value
FROM person p, detailTypes t
LEFT JOIN details d
    ON p.idPerson = d.idPerson AND t.type = d.type
```

But MySQL (5.5.32) / PHPMyAdmin complains that "unknown column 'p.idPerson' in 'on clause'". You can it round to:

```
SELECT name, field, value
FROM detailTypes t, person p
LEFT JOIN details d
    ON p.idPerson = d.idPerson AND t.type = d.type
```

and it has the same complaint, except that t.type is now unknown.

The current solution is a *[shudder]* nested query, like this:

```
SELECT name, field, value
FROM (
    SELECT type, field, idPerson
    FROM person p, detailsType t
) pt
LEFT JOIN pt.idPerson = p.idPerson AND pt.type = t.type
```

Is this a known problem with MySQL? Is it that my first queries are just plain wrong? Can I do it a better way? Cos it doesn't seem right to me ....

Comment: You already got four answers. At least you could show some enthusiasm, don't you?

Comment: correct your schema first

Comment: @amenadiel Give me a second dude, I typed this out then went for some food ;)

Comment: @Karunakar - corrected, was just a typo on my part

Comment: with old schema defnation my proposed query will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "type" field in any of your tables. Did you meant to use `idDetailType` ? Try the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM detailTypes t 
JOIN person p 
LEFT JOIN details d ON p.idPerson = d.idPerson AND t.idDetailType = d.idDetailType
```

Then refine the results to avoid using that nasty `*`

PD: field and value are reserved keywords. There might be some unexpected behaviors because of this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the status to comment yet so I write here.
Have you tried setting your 'p' and 't' values as primary keys for the tables?

Comment: Because the query you wrote seem okay to me.

Comment: Heya @RKrogh - yeah, the query works fine, I just wondered if it was possible to do it without a nested query in a way that won't cause errors in MySQL. Upvoted ya to get you a bit more status ...

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Being able to comment would help a lot in keeping the good structure of the site.

I see the query was solved. Great!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a single query

```
    SELECT p.name, t.field, dt.value
    FROM person p INNER JOIN detailTypes dt ON p.idPerson=dt.idPerson
    LEFT JOIN details d ON d.idDetailType=dt.idDetailType
```

Comment: This has already been tried & is the reason for the error, see the question ;)

I agree with you btw, I think that *should* be the correct query, but it causes the error stated in mysql ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT temp.name, temp.typeName as field, d.value
FROM (select * from person, detailTypes) temp
 LEFT JOIN details d
ON temp.idPerson = d.idPerson AND temp.typeName = d.idDetailType
```

Comment: This is a rewrite of the last query tried in the question; the one I'm using at the moment. It certainly works, but I wanted to know if there was a better query, cos I don't think that's the right one ...

Comment: My schema + queries were a little inconsistent - my fault. Your answer's correct in as much as, to the old schema, they worked whereas mine wouldn't have ... but the actual query is pretty similar in how it works ...